# Errors using Ocrad.js on the canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'd like use Ocrad.js and to start I'd like to make a simpler version of http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html.
To familiarize with the library I wrote this simple example but the text doesn't get recognized correctly (I always get a '.' as output).

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ocrad.js/ocrad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/test.js"> </script>
<title>ocradjs test</title>test.js

</head>
<body>
<canvas id="OCRArea" width="800" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"  > </canvas>
<div id="image"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my js/test.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var ch;
        var cw;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("OCRArea");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imgData ;
        ctx.font="100px Georgia";
        ctx.fillText("Test!",10,100);
        cw = canvas.width;
        ch = canvas.height;

        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch);
        console.log(OCRAD(imgData));
        console.log(OCRAD(canvas));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's Canvas only I was also fillText, "-" was investigated because it is recognized as .

When the background is transparent but , unfortunately characters are not recognized .

Please try the following .

```
var ch;
var cw;
var canvas = document.getElementById("OCRArea");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imgData ;

cw = canvas.width;
ch = canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";

ctx.font="100px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Test!",10,100);

imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch);
console.log(OCRAD(imgData));
```